# Initialize Point Array from String

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, split, converters

Their is a fast way (one or two lines) to convert `string` to `Point[]`?

My string: `"10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";`

Wanted result:

```
Point[] point = new Point[5] 
{
    new Point(10, 10),
    new Point(10, 20),
    new Point(20, 20),
    new Point(20, 10),
    new Point(10, 10)
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string s = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";
var points = s.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Split(','))
              .Select(y=>new Point(int.Parse(y[0]),int.Parse(y[1])))
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Great! Their is a way to do this also to this array: "10,10,10,20,20,20,20,10,10,10"? (Just Commas)

Answer (score 2):

Regex can be used too

```
string input = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";
Point[] points = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+),(\d+)").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => new Point(int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one

```
"10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10".Split(';');
```

Split at every `;` in the String. Then take out each element, and convert it to a Point.

```
string mainString = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";
string[] stringArray = mainString..Split(';');
Point[] pointArray;
// convert them
foreach (var point in stringArray) {
  // each object in array.
   var eachItem = point.Split(','); // you have [10, 10]
   var x = eachItem[0];
   var y = eachItem[1];
   Point pointItem = new Point(x, y);
   pointArray.Add(pointItem);
}
```

And you're done! It won't be a single line. Actually one line codes are for converting object to object. But since you're going to take out data from an object and then working on it, after that converting it to some other data type. That is why, you'll be required to work on it.

Above code shows how you can create array of the data and then convert it into a single point, after that push those points to a point array.

Comment: The result of this is string[]. I need Point[]

Comment: @inon, I was writing it out, sorry for delay. Have your answer now.

Comment: One or two can be made out of this code, if you simply just remove the white spaces and the new line characters. Then it would be a single (but long) row.

Answer (score 0):

Not as short as you'd like -- but this will work:

```
var values = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";
var result = new List<Point>();

foreach (var point in values.Split(';'))
{
    var split = point.Split(',');
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
    var y = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
    result.Add(new Point(x, y));
}
```

This makes the assumption that 1) a List is okay. If not, call ToArray and 2) you control the data coming in and are certain that Convert.ToIn32 will never fail.

Edit -

Here's your one line solution :)

```
var values = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10"; var result = new List<Point>(); foreach (var point in values.Split(';')) { var split = point.Split(','); var x = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]); var y = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]); result.Add(new Point(x, y)); }
```

The reality is that I do not think this is doable in a single line. Why do you want a single line? Is the above solution running too slow? I doubt that's the case.

Comment: @inon: "one line of code" doesn't necessarily mean the resulting code is faster or easier to maintain. Even with Linq you are still splitting the string and then iterating over that collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var instring = "10,10;10,20;20,20;20,10;10,10";
var points =
    instring.Split(';')
    .Select(a => a.Split(','))
    .Select(a => new Point(Convert.ToInt32(a[0]), Convert.ToInt32(a[1])))
    .ToArray();
```

There's a one liner using linq, though it doesn't do any sanity checking on the input.